# Git server-side hooks sometimes do not execute on the server side?

Tags: git, githooks

I understand that the script is ran on the remote repo, but which context does the script execute in? Does it use the resources of the client machine or the resources of the server machine? Or does it change depending on how the client repo communicates with the remote repo. I can't seem to find this information officially documented anywhere.

Edit:

I should've probably formulated my question differently. Anyway, I just ran into this:

https://superuser.com/questions/974337/when-i-run-a-git-hook-in-a-repo-on-a-network-share-which-binaries-are-used

which mentions that "If it’s a regular (SMB/CIFS) network share, it’s executed on the client." When doing `git remote -v` from within the local repo it shows the local protocol (file://) mapped to origin, and pushing to the remote on the network share ends up using the Perl on my client, instead of the Perl on the server, verified with `perl --version`. So what I really wanted to ask is given this information, how can this be if they're "server-side" hooks? Shouldn't they ALWAYS run on the server regardless? This is on Windows btw.

Comment: Server-side hooks run on the server (otherwise they'd be called client-side hooks :-) ).  They run *after* all new objects are already in the repository.  The pre-receive and update hooks run *before* any references are updated, while the post-receive hook runs *after* all references are updated.

Comment: Ah: if you push to a *local* file system (`file://foo`) then the "server" is your own machine, i.e., the client is your machine but so is the server, so when the "server" runs something, it's your client doing the running.  I don't use Windows so I cannot say which protocols it might consider "local" (the *protocol* is the `https:` or `ssh:` or `file:` part of `https://host.dom.ain/path` or `ssh://host.dom.ain/path` or `file://path` URL). (Incidentally, I didn't downvote your original question, because I do think these are not documented very well.)

Comment: No worries, after reflecting on how I originally worded the question and reading your first comment, I realized how stupid my question sounded. I'm more concerned on getting a definitive answer anyway. Thanks for confirming that it isn't documented very well. Hm, I'd like to mark your most recent comment as the answer, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer now that I understand the basic premise of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now understand where this particular bit of confusion comes from.  Obviously "server side" hooks run on the server—but if you run `git push` to a remote whose URL is `file://...` (or just a path like `/some/path/to/repo`), and in the various server-side hooks, have the server print its host name, or software version, or whatever, you will find that those are your own machine's software version, etc.

The trick here is that when you are dealing with a local path, your Git acts as both client *and* server, talking to itself.  This is true even if your local file system is network-based, as long as Git itself sees it as local.  Hence for NFS, or CIFS/Samba, or (if you use such things) an Andrew File System mount or a Plan9 mount or FUSE or whatever, as long as Git thinks it's just a regular old file on your own machine, Git does all the server work itself, so these are still local.

(In fact, if you run `ps` on a Unix/Linux system, you'll see that your client has forked a `git receive-pack` process:

```
remote:   PID  PPID TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
[snip]
remote: 28494 27867  4  S+     0:00.06 git push me testbr
remote: 28495 28494  4  S+     0:00.07 git-receive-pack /home/torek/tmp/t
remote: 28499 28495  4  S+     0:00.01 /bin/sh hooks/pre-receive
remote: 28500 28499  4  R+     0:00.00 ps -O ppid
```

so in effect, process 28494 is the "client" here, while process 28495 is the "server".  Both are, of course, on one single host / VM / whatever.  I set up remote `me` to point to `file:///home/torek/tmp/t` here.)